# What will DynamoDB Mapper batchLoad return if no items exist?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'm sure for DynamoDBMapper.load(), if try to query database but find nothing it will return null.

But what about DynamoDBMapper.batchLoad()? 
public Map> batchLoad(Iterable itemsToGet)

The documentation only saying:
A map of the loaded objects. Each key in the map is the name of a DynamoDB table. Each value in the map is a list of objects that have been loaded from that table. All objects for each table can be cast to the associated user defined type that is annotated as mapping that table.

So I guess it won't return null, but an empty Map or even Empty List?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will return an empty `Map`.

To verify, check the code at https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapper.java.

Comment: I carefully read the code, I think actually they have processBatchGetRequest, which contains table name and List<Objects>. So I feel like it'll return non-empty Map. Wondering which line exactly make you think it''l return empty Map? THX

Comment: `resultSet` is declared as an empty map and is filled up with data in `processBatchGetRequest()`. If nothing found, `resultSet` remains empty and is returned as it is.

Comment: Also design principles say that a method returning a collection should never return null, instead should return an empty collections if no data is found.